# How to resolve the "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError" on Mac terminal?

Tags: java, jar, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have a jar file 'myApp.jar' that I need to run through command line. When I run the jar on linux server it working perfect. However, when I tried to the same jar on mac terminal I am getting this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: while loading kognac-core: Stream closed
    at karmaresearch.vlog.VLog.loadLibrary(VLog.java:72)
    at karmaresearch.vlog.VLog.<clinit>(VLog.java:22)
    at org.semanticweb.rulewerk.reasoner.vlog.VLogReasoner.<init>(VLogReasoner.java:82)
    at org.semanticweb.rulewerk.client.picocli.MyApp.someMethod(MyApp.java:150)
    at org.semanticweb.rulewerk.client.picocli.MyApp.main(MyApp.java:110)
```

The command that I used to run the jar is:

```
java -jar myApp.java
```

The jar file is compiled and created by `javaSE-1.8` through Eclipse on Mac.
The java version of Linux server is `openjdk version "1.8.0_292"`
The java versions on Mac are 3:  `Java SE 11.0.1`(default version) , `1.8.0_202`, `1.8.0_201` by these commands:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -jar myApp.java
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -jar myApp.java
```

I tried to run the jar file on mac with all 3 java versions, but still getting the same error above.

How could I resolve this error on Mac terminal?

Comment: Do you have a source code of this app? I'd like to see `org.semanticweb.rulewerk.client.picocli.MyApp` implementation, that would help to understand the problem.

Comment: Yes, but it very long code that why I did not include it here.

Comment: At least include the method around line `110` where the problem happens.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't related to your app or how you run it.

Your app uses the `karmaresearch` project which I'm not familiar with (possibly, that's *your own* code, that you / your team wrote?) and this code attempts to load a so-called native library: These are libraries compiled straight for the OS/architecture your JVM is running on top of.

These take the form of a `.jnilib` file on mac, `.dll` on windows, and `.so` on linux and other posix-based OSes.

Native libraries are incredibly convoluted to ship: You need 1 such file for each combination of OS and underlying architecture. So, these days, you'd need at a minimum to make a reasonable claim that you're 'portable':

- Mac AAarch64
- Mac x84
- Windows x64
- Linux AArch64
- Linux x64
- Linux x32
- BSD x64

and that's just a bare bones minimum.

These files **cannot** be inside the jar when you load them. The usual procedure is to obtain a location you can write to *and* load code out of (tricky), unpack the right file for the host OS to this folder, and then `loadLibrary` it. This is all very complicated. In general, either [A] you wrote karmaresearch and you need to think long and hard about using native libraries first, and if you truly need it, follow a tutorial, or [B] it's not your code, in which case you can't run this on a mac, at all, and there's nothing you can do about that, other than contact the makers of this library and ask them to add support for this.

Comment: Yes, I use library that not created by me. I just added some features to it and export it as Jar file.

Comment: Well, then you have your answer. That library simply does not and will never run on a mac unless its developers add support for it.

Comment: but it run through Eclipse on mac

Comment: Ah, then something else is going on. As I explained in the answer, the library needs to do a lot of work to make native libraries function properly, such as unpacking it from the jar. This part is not working (i.e. the library you are using is bugged), or the library expects you to put the `.jnilib` file in some specific place on your own, i.e. there is some installation procedure.